# tortoisesvn revision numbers: same number, different contents?

Tags: tortoisesvn

With a trunk and a branch, on a project, shouldn't the revision log show the same contents for a specific file's revision number (e.g. 123), regardless of whether it was viewed on the branch or trunk?

I'm looking at the file revision 123 via both the trunk and branch log and the contents are definitely different. I have been messing around with merges, but how would this affect historic files?

I'm totally baffled by this as I would expect them to be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at a the repository via a specific revision number, you see the state of that directory at the specific revision(*).  This means that say the branch was created at revision 99; if a file was modified at revision 100 in the branch, and revision 101 in the trunk you will see different contents for the file in the two directories.

(*) same for the HEAD revision, although the number is implicit in that case (resolving to the latest revision number available)

Comment: Of course. It's obvious when you spell it out like that. So, if I want to compare differences between versions on the  branch and trunk, I'd need to do it differently to the way I was attempting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> With a trunk and a branch, on a project, shouldn't the revision log show the same contents for a specific file's revision number (e.g. 123), regardless of whether it was viewed on the branch or trunk?

Not if it's a revision *after* the branch was created.